# Just Works pairing with BlueZ

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm trying to pair from a Linux host (ARM based, Angstrom distribution) to a MCU driven embedded device using [BLE Just Works Secure Connection](https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluetooth-pairing-part-4/). As a device I'm currently using an ESP32 dev kit flashed with the GATT security [example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/ble/gatt_security_server). However, so far my tries weren't successful and I failed to find the according documentation, either.

I managed to pair my Android smartphone with the device, so pairing on the device side, in general, seems to work. I also tried to conduct the pairing without a Secure Connection (setting Authorization Request to SP_LE_AUTH_BOND) which worked with `bluetoothctl` or `btmgmt`.

I'm grateful for any documentation pointer how to perform pairing from the command line, Python scripting or any C/C++ code.

Comment: Please clarify "weren't successful" and include what happens.

Comment: I tried to use the ```pair``` command from ```btmgmt```: ```pair -c 0x03 -t 0x02 <ADDRESS>``` and the ```pair``` comand from ```bluetoothctl``` but received inconclusive error messages like ```fail_reason: 0x55``` on the ESP32 and an ```unspecified error``` that authentication failed from BlueZ.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer below and the included references; these cover pairing using BlueZ/Linux:-

[Raspberry Pi BLE Encryption/Pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62242352/2215147)

If this still doesn't work, please launch "btmon" on another terminal before starting the pairing process as that will give you an indication as to what is going wrong.

I hope this helps.