# Correct way to turn on Bluetooth discovery on Ubuntu command line

Tags: bluetooth

Looks like there are two different options to put Bluetooth in discovery mode:

First method:

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
#discoverable on
#pairable on
#agent on
#default-agent
```

Second method:

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
```

Second method seems to be simpler. Is there any problem in using the second method? When does the first method make sense?

Answer (score 3):

The first method should be used going forward because `hciconfig` has been [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) along with a few other command line tools. I believe they are still bundled in your OS either because you have an older version of the OS or maybe because there's a grace period before the tools are fully removed.

You can also use `btmgmt` to get your device to be discoverable/connectable/pairable. The difference is that `btmgmt` is considered to be more system related while `bluetoothctl` is application-related. See this answer below for more information:-

[Raspberry BLE Encryption / Pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147384/raspberry-ble-encryption-pairing/62242352#62242352)