# Bluetooth Low Energy Pairing/Bonding Device Problem

Tags: javascript, python, ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to pair a BLE Device (requiring PIN) with my Raspberry Pi.

I can scan and pair it by using "sudo bluetoothctl pair <Device MAC's Address>". But after a few minutes, the pairing is disconnected.

I have tried bluepy program which can pair Pi with XIAO BLE (not require PIN) to pair Pi with the device too but the result is can not pair.

In the device's app, I have to enter a PIN code in the first time paring. After this, the PIN code is not required. So I think this connection is bonding but I'm not getting sure.

The "sudo bluetoothctl pair" command didn't ask me for any PIN code, it just connected directly and disconnected for a while.

So, I want to ask for a solution to pair Raspberry Pi with my device.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is happening because you don't have the keyboard IO capability set on your Raspberry Pi. Try the steps in the answer below and see if that resolves your problem:-

- [Raspberry Pi BLE Encryption/Pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147384/raspberry-ble-encryption-pairing/62242352#62242352)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I realized that the PIN I have to type in the device's app is a type of signing combined with the data sent to the device. The device is not required a PIN code.